# full access to remote computer without remote static IP

Tags: ssh, networking

How can I access to remote computer that the remote computer is in a local network?
I worked with reverse ssh  : `http://www.vdomck.org/2005/11/reversing-ssh-connection.html`
I don't want just SSH but I want other port's of remote computer too
I want to connect to remote computer by http,ssh ,mysql,ppp,... ports
How can I do that?

Answer (score 3):

If the ports aren't firewalled, then you just a need a mechanism for finding out the remote machine's IP address - which could, as Hanan N. suggests, be using a dynamic DNS service - or just roll your own method for registering the address (NB a lot of ISPs now use transparent HTTP proxying - so might not be a good idea to send this data over port 80).

But if you've can get ssh running then you can run [pppd on top of ssh](http://tldp.org/HOWTO/ppp-ssh/) to establish a VPN connection

Comment: You don't need pppd for an SSH vpn. OpenSSH has the "Tunnel" option, which establishes a VPN link. The SSH server disallows tunnels by default. The "PermitTunnel" option in sshd_config can be used to allow tunnels.  Note that using SSH as a VPN can cause significant performance problems; see http://sites.inka.de/bigred/devel/tcp-tcp.html for a discussion of the issue.  If possible, it's better to use a VPN that uses UDP or IPSec as a transport.

Comment: Last time I looked in depth at this support for tunnel varied a bit - maybe I'm a bit out of date. Regarding performance, I'd found only about a 10% overhead using ppp over SSL with no measurable jitter - although you do need to tune the MTU

Answer (score 2):

You basically need two things:

1. Create a free account on [dyndns](https://account.dyn.com/entrance/) service, and install a [program](http://download.cnet.com/DynDNS-Updater/3000-2381_4-10405775.html) on your computer or better config your router to use their service (in case you have DD-WRT installed on it), that would map a name that is associated with your current public IP that your ISP gave you. With that name you can create connection with your router from anyware in the world no matter what is the IP you have got since the dyndns service update the name to associate with your current IP address.
2. You should forward from your router the desired port you want to point to your local computer IP address, you can set the router to open port 5001 and each time it get an IP packet from the outside world it should forward that to the IP address you have set it to forward to.

Comment: I used to use dyn, I use no-ip.org now.

Comment: @Rob: great, it is same thing, i am too using no-ip.

Answer (score 1):

What about a reverse socks proxy? Using the `-D` switch.

Comment: ssh -D from my client to the server?! Can you explain it?

Comment: Let the clients on the server connect to the socks server over there. Ssh can then tunnel those connections to services on the client.

Answer (score 0):

Use any dynamic dns services (like dyndns.org). You need to install service's client (client from dyndns is present in most repositories) and it sends your current ip to their servers. And they update a-name domain records. Therefore you have free third-level domain with always up-to-date information about your current ip.

Comment: What's the value of the IP address, if that computer is behind a NAT (masquerading)?..

Comment: You can use dynamic dns if you're able to forward ports to your computer. Otherwise there is noway to solve this problem. Of course you can use ipv6 tunnel, but, unfortunately, most internet users dont't have ipv6 at all.

Comment: Ok, forwarding ports is another part of the solution. Simply knowing the IP address (the only thing discussed in this answer) gives little.

Comment: Is there any Free sofrware for this purpose? , I don't want to use any proprietary software

Answer (score 0):

If you don't have a public IP, you can use [SSH over XMPP/Jabber protocol](http://awangga.wordpress.com/2013/08/27/ssh-access-without-ip-public-from-mobile-phone-or-computer/).
So you can get access with just Google Talk on your desktop or mobile phone (e.g. Android).